# HTML horizontal list truncate to two rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list of items that are laid out horizontally and they will go the full width of their containing element and then they will wrap on the next line. But I want to only display two lines of items and then have a "show more" link that will show two more rows at a time until all rows are displayed.

Here is what my markup looks like. This works fine, except I am not sure how to show only the first two rows of this. Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be done? I don't know the width of the containing element (it could stretch or shrink at will and if it does, the two rows still need to adapt to the new width).

```css
.items {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  max-height:30px;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-inner {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.item-text {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 11px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="items">
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 1</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 2</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 3</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 4</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 5</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 6</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 7</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 8</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 9</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 10</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 11</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 12</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 13</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 14</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 15</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 16</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 17</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 18</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 19</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 20</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 21</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 22</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 23</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 24</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 25</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 26</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 27</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 28</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 29</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 30</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 31</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 32</span></span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Does it have to be dynamic columns or can it have a predefined number of columns?

Comment: What about starting with a wrapper element like `.items` and set overflow hidden with a max-height to begin with?

Comment: @imvain2 It needs to be a dynamic width. This could be on a desktop or a mobile device and also the width of the browser could be changed and so this would need to adapt to whatever width the containing element is. And if the containing element changes width (such as if the browser is stretched and made wider), then the number of rows displayed might change. So in that case, it might be possible that it could go from three rows down to two rows, in which case the "show more" link should disappear. Or it could go from two rows to three, in which case the "show more" link should be displayed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That is a really good idea. I can try that. Do you know how to make it so that the "show more" link could be hidden or displayed as the browser width is changed? For example, if the browser width is such that there are only two rows and it gets shrunk to make it so there are three rows displayed, do you know how to display the link as the width changes?

Comment: @ashipma sure, using JS you'll have to attach an Event listener towards `"resize"` but also on DOM ready obviously. When it triggers, iterate over all the `.items` on a page, - then in order to toggle that *Show more/less* button it's simple as detecting if an `.items` `scrollHeight` has a higher value than its `clientHeight`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just tried the first suggestion you gave about setting the overflow and max-height on a wrapper element, but I cannot get that to work. I updated the code snippet to have the `.items` wrapper and the CSS for that. I just set it to 30px for the height right now, but I would actually calculate the height of two rows eventually. I am just trying to get it to clip the contents right now, but I cannot seem to get that to work. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it.

first set all the items inside a div and add above the items another div for  "show more".

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="next" onclick="changeHeight()">
        <span class="nextText">Show more<span>
    </div>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 1</span></span></span>
.........
</div>
```

Then add JS script for onclick event.

```
<script>
        function changeHeight(){
            const cont = document.querySelector('.container');
            const divInnerContentHeight = cont.scrollHeight;
            const divClientHeight = cont.clientHeight;
            
            console.log(divInnerContentHeight);
            console.log(divClientHeight);
            
            if(divClientHeight < divInnerContentHeight){
                cont.setAttribute("style",`height:${divClientHeight + 80}px`);
                if(divClientHeight+ 80 >= divInnerContentHeight)
                    document.querySelector('.nextText').innerHTML = "Show less";
            }
            else{
                cont.setAttribute("style",'height:91px');
                document.querySelector('.nextText').innerHTML = "Show more";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Here the final result.

```js
function changeHeight(){
            const cont = document.querySelector('.container');
            const divInnerContentHeight = cont.scrollHeight;
            const divClientHeight = cont.clientHeight;
            
            //console.log(divInnerContentHeight);
            //console.log(divClientHeight);
            
            if(divClientHeight < divInnerContentHeight){
                cont.setAttribute("style",`height:${divClientHeight + 80}px`);
                if(divClientHeight+ 80 >= divInnerContentHeight)
                    document.querySelector('.nextText').innerHTML = "Show less";
            }
            else{
                cont.setAttribute("style",'height:91px');
                document.querySelector('.nextText').innerHTML = "Show more";
            }
        }
```

```css
.container{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 91px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.next {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #d9cece;
    text-align: center;
}
.next:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .item {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-inner {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.item-text {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 11px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="next" onclick="changeHeight()">
        <span class="nextText">Show more<span>
    </div>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 1</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 2</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 3</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 4</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 5</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 6</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 7</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 8</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 9</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 10</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 11</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 12</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 13</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 14</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 15</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 16</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 17</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 18</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 19</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 20</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 21</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 22</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 23</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 24</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 25</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 26</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 27</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 28</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 29</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 30</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 31</span></span></span>
    <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 32</span></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Fist of, inline `onclick` should not be used. Secondly, how it this supposed to be responsive? Where's the `"resize"` listener?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the height of the elements, my answer first loops through the items and calculates which row they would be grouped by their **top** value.

Then the read more button just sets the max height of the parent element to the height of the elements multiplied by the row number. I also hide the read more button once the last row is displayed

```js
function loadReadMore() {
  const items = document.querySelector(".items");
  const allItems = items.querySelectorAll(".items .item");
  const readMore = document.querySelector(".readMore");

  let rows = 0;
  let curTop = 0;
  const maxHeight = 40;
  let row = 1;

  items.style["max-height"] = maxHeight + "px";

  allItems.forEach((el) => {
    let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    el.dataset.height = rect.height + "px";
    if (curTop < el.offsetTop) {
      curTop = el.offsetTop;
      rows++;
    }

    el.dataset.row = rows;
  });

  readMore.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (row < rows) {
      row++;
      items.style["max-height"] = (maxHeight * row) + "px";

      if (row == rows) {
        readMore.classList.add("hide")
      }
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('resize', loadReadMore)
loadReadMore();
```

```css
.items {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.item-inner {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.item-text {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 11px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 1</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 2</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 3</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 4</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 5</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 6</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 7</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 8</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 9</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 10</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 11</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 12</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 13</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 14</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 15</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 16</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 17</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 18</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 19</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 20</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 21</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 22</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 23</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 24</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 25</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 26</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 27</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 28</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 29</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 30</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 31</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="item"><span class="item-inner"><span class="item-text">Item 32</span></span>
  </span>
</div>
<button class="readMore">Read More</button>
```